# jquery datatables how to render and sort mm-dd-yyyy

Tags: datatables

I have implemented datatables and have been trying for several hours to get the data to display and sort properly to no avail.  I wish to display the data as mm-dd-yy. I could use mm/dd/yy, but I have pre 2000 dates, so the 99's sort highest instead of lowest.  I changed the data to send a 4 digit year, but do not want to display it.  I tried this:

```
$('#shiporderinfotable').dataTable( {
    "data": dataSet,
    "columns": [
        { "title": "Store", "class": "dr" },
        { "title": "Order#", "class": "dr" },
        { "title": "Cust PO#", "class": "dl" },
        { "title": "Order Date", "class": "dr" },
        { "title": "Invoice", "class": "dr" },
        { "title": "Inv Date", "class": "dr" },
        { "title": "Qty<br>Ord", "class": "dr" },
        { "title": "Qty<br>Shp", "class": "dr" },
        { "title": "Qty<br>Open", "class": "dr" },
        { "title": "Qty<br>Pick", "class": "dr" },
        { "title": "Pick<br>Date", "class": "dr" },
        { "title": "Items", "class": "dl" }
    ],
    "columnDefs": [ 
        {

            "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                return data.substr(0,2)+'-'+data.substr(3,2)+'-'+data.substr(8,2);
            },
            "targets": [3,5,10]
        }]
} );
```

if I take out the render statement, it sorts fine.  Once I add the render statement, it is doing a left justified character sort.  Is there a way to do the render only for display and not sorting?

Comment: You can have a column for display and another hidden column for the sorting. Have a look at [iDataSort](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns#iDataSort)

Comment: Just to verify, if I load the data in another column, I could set it to not display and then render back to the original date column in whatever format I like and then set the hidden column to be the sort column, correct?  This would eliminate needing to send the date twice, once formatted and another in 4 year format for sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above comment by markpsmith answered the question.  I added this answer to be able to close it.  I came up with the code listed below.  I loaded 3 extra columns of date data formatted mm/dd/yyyy and left the listed date columns blank.  I then set the sorting to use those columns and rendered the display for the columns mm-dd-yy.

```
 $.ajax({url:arg,success:function(result){
$('#shiporderinfo').html( '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="shiporderinfotable" width="100%"></table>' );
var dataSet = eval(result);
$('#shiporderinfotable').dataTable( {
    "data": dataSet,
    "columns": [
        { "title": "Store", "class": "dr" },
        { "title": "Order#", "class": "dr" },
        { "title": "Cust PO#", "class": "dl" },
        { "title": "Order Date", "class": "dr", "iDataSort": 12 },
        { "title": "Invoice", "class": "dr" },
        { "title": "Inv Date", "class": "dr", "iDataSort": 13 },
        { "title": "Qty<br>Ord", "class": "dr" },
        { "title": "Qty<br>Shp", "class": "dr" },
        { "title": "Qty<br>Open", "class": "dr" },
        { "title": "Qty<br>Pick", "class": "dr" },
        { "title": "Pick<br>Date", "class": "dr", "iDataSort": 14 },
        { "title": "Items", "class": "dl" },
        { "title": "Order Date Sort", "visible": false },
        { "title": "Invoice Date Sort", "visible": false },
        { "title": "Pick Date Sort", "visible": false }
    ]
    ,"order": [[ 3, "desc" ]]
    ,"lengthMenu": [[10, 20, 50, 100, -1], [10, 20, 50, 100, "All"]]
    ,
    "columnDefs": [ 
        {
            "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                tmp = row[12];
                if (tmp == '') {
                 return '';
                } else {
                 return tmp.substr(0,2)+'-'+tmp.substr(3,2)+'-'+tmp.substr(8,2);
                }
            },
            "targets": [3]
        },{
            "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                tmp = row[13];
                if (tmp == '') {
                 return '';
                } else {
                 return tmp.substr(0,2)+'-'+tmp.substr(3,2)+'-'+tmp.substr(8,2);
                }
            },
            "targets": [5]
        },{
        "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                tmp = row[14];
                if (tmp == '') {
                 return '';
                } else {
                 return tmp.substr(0,2)+'-'+tmp.substr(3,2)+'-'+tmp.substr(8,2);
                }
            },
            "targets": [10]
        }]
} );
$('.ajax-order-popup').magnificPopup({type: 'ajax',closeOnContentClick: true});
```

}});